# Update text within a DIV on an extrernal HTML page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dhtml

I currently have a web page which when a user types something into a text box it automatically updates the same text in a DIV on that page. Using the code below;

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#someTextBox').keyup(function(){
      $('#form').html($(this).val());
    });
   });
</script>
```

I currently EMBED another web page within the HTML page and was wondering weather I could dynamically change a DIV within this EMBEDED page from the text box on the container page?

So when a user types something into the text box it updates the #form DIV on the embed page?

I'm not sure if this is possible but wanted to ask.

Thanks

Comment: Depends largely on what “embedding” means.

Comment: `<object data="websitepage" width="1000" height="500"> <embed src=webpage width="1000" height="400"> </embed> Error: Embedded data could not be displayed. </object>`

Comment: And is that embedded page from the same domain? Otherwise the Same origin Policy will stop you right there.

Comment: Yes it is just another page in the same directory

Comment: Well using an `iframe` to embed the other document would allow for easier access to it … with `object` that’s a bit of a hassle. The `contentDocument` property of the `iframe` element refers to the document object of the page loaded into the iframe, so it’s quite easy to go from there.

Comment: so if i change the embed to an `iframe` can the javascript refer to `DIVS` within that embded page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe